# Web application form post not receiving a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I have a form

```
 <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="myFile" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

I also have some C# code

```
 if (Request["submit"] == "submit") {
       Response.Write(Request.Files.Count);
 }
```

If a user chooses a file on their system and submits, What reasons could there be for me seeing a "0" instead of a "1" in the `Request.Files.Count` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `enctype` attribute to your `<form>`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
```

Comment: @Alex C, no problem glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any kind of ajax (i.e. update panel) then you have to make sure you're doing a full page post back when submitting not a partial page postback.